# get the common mac addresses on mac os using java

Tags: java, osx-lion

I'm building a java application that gets the mac addresses of a user and compare it with the correspondent value in the database(security feature). but the problem happens on mac os when i discovered that the list of mac addresses has common values(ex: on my mac the list of mac addresses are: 001C42000009,001C42000008,E0F8474267B6(wifi),70CD60F1A5C1(ethernet))
Is there a way to know all these common values that will result when getting the Mac address on Mac os.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At http://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/oui/public.html you can lookup a vendor using first 3 bytes of the MAC address, 00-1C-42 points to "Parallels, Inc." (http://www.parallels.com). Are you using some of their virtualization software? Try what `java.net.NetworkInterface.isVirtual()` returns for this address, if that is not useful then some ugly filter may require (e.g. based on address pattern)

```
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class NetworkInterfaceTest {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ie = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
      while (ie.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface i = ie.nextElement();
        System.out.println(i.getDisplayName() + " [" + i.getName() + "]: " + formatAddress(i.getHardwareAddress()) + "; isVirtual=" + i.isVirtual());
      }
    } catch (Exception e){ 
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static String formatAddress(byte[] address) {
    if (address == null) {
      return null;
    }

    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(address.length * 2);
    for (byte b : address) {
      if (ret.length() > 0) {
        ret.append('-');
      }

      String bs = Integer.toHexString(b & 0x000000FF).toUpperCase();
      if (bs.length() < 2) {
        ret.append('0');
      }
      ret.append(bs);
    }

    return ret.toString();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe something like this will do the work for you

```
try {
    InetAddress []addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
    /*
     * Get NetworkInterfaces for current host and read hardware addresses.
     */
    for(int j=0; j< addresses.length; i++) {
            System.out.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < addresses.length – 1) ? "-" : "");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```